# Macro to copy & paste rows to new sheet if value is > 0 error

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on an excel workbook with multiple sheets, on Sheet8 I have two columns (A & B) which pull data from all of the sheets via a vlookup based on column A and return either a 0 or >0 answer in column B.

I have been trying to get a macro to copy the rows on Sheet8 where the value in column B is >0 and paste them into either Sheet12 or a new workbook entirely but the code is foxing me completely.

Below is the code I am currently working with, which throws a Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range error.

```
Sub CSVCreate()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet8")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet12")

lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = ws1.Range("B1:B" & lr)

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value > 0 Then
        cell.EntireRow.Copy
        If ws2.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
            ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Else
            ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    End If
Next cell

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: Check if the sheet name is actually `Sheet8` and `Sheet12`. And also ensure that you are referring to the right workbook. One last thing. If "visually" you see the names as `Sheet8` and `Sheet12`, then ensure there are no leading or trailing spaces. You can verify it by going to the worksheet and double clicking on the sheet tab. OR you can use Code Names to be on a safer side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CSVCreate()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet,ws2 As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws1 = .Sheets("Sheet8")
        Set ws2 = .Sheets("Sheet12")
    End With

    With ws1

        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range("B1:B" & lr)

    End With

    For Each cell In rng

        If cell.Value > 0 Then

            cell.EntireRow.Copy

            With ws2

                If .Range("A1").Value = "" Then
                    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Else
                    .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End If

            End With

        End If

    Next cell

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Note:

If you receive errors on the below lines that means you dont have such sheet names.

```
Set ws1 = .Sheets("Sheet8")
Set ws2 = .Sheets("Sheet12")
```